# Как вывести sql запрос в WP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Небходимо в файле page.php вывести результаты по запросу:

```
SELECT SUM(option_value) FROM $wpdb->wp_options WHERE option_name like 'floor_%_availableArea'
```

пробовал сделать вот так, но не выходит

```
<?php $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_options WHERE option_name like 'floor_%_availableArea'")?> <?php echo $posts[0]->option_value; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался:

```
<?php $freearea = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(option_value) FROM wp_options WHERE option_name like 'floor_%_availableArea' "); print_r($freearea); ?>
```